# R package amt: How to calculate different amounts of random locations for different individuals

Tags: r, random, location

My data set consists of more than 50.000 locations ($ longitude and $ latitude) of 25 GPS collard animals with a date time stamp ($ acquisition_time) and some additional info (age class, sex, study area). I am working with the package amt for the first time and I am stuck trying to derive the random points for each individual within its home range.

My code so far:

```
library(purrr)
library(amt)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate)
library(sf) 
library(sp)
library(plyr)
library(mapview)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

#load data
dat <- read.csv('wildcat_data_ready.csv')

#prepare data
dat$acquisition_time = as.POSIXct(dat$acquisition_time, 
                                  tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

dat1 <- as_tibble(dat) %>% dplyr::select (x = longitude, y = latitude,
                  t = acquisition_time,id=animals_id, sex=animals_sex, 
                  age = animals_age_class, area = study_area_id)

#change projection to LAEA & add day and night
trk <- dat1 %>% make_track(x, y, t, id = id, sex = sex, age = age, area = area, 
                  crs = sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326")) %>% 
                  transform_coords(sp::CRS("+init=epsg:3035")) %>% 
                  amt::time_of_day(include.crepuscule = FALSE)

#get information about time resolution of fixes
info_trk <- trk %>% summarize_sampling_rate_many(c("id"), time_unit="hour")
info_trk 

#ensure locations are recorded 6 hours apart
trk1 <- trk %>% nest(data = -"id")

trk1 <- trk1 %>% mutate(resample = map(data, function(a) {
                  a %>% amt::track_resample(rate = hours(6),
                  tolerance = minutes(20))
  }))

# calculate kde 95% home range
trk2 <- trk1 %>% mutate(hr = map(resample, function(x) {
                  x %>% hr_kde(levles = 0.95)}))

trk2 <- trk2 %>% mutate(hr1 = map(hr, function(y) {
                  y%>% hr_isopleths()
  }))

# calculate random points in individuals home range 
trk_id <- trk2 %>% mutate(random_used = map(hr1, function(z) {
                  z %>% random_points(n=100)
  }))
```

Here is a sample from my original data:

```
> dat[886:898,]
    animals_id    acquisition_time longitude latitude      projection collar_type
886          1 2011-12-27 23:59:00  7.588487 47.91844 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
887          1 2011-12-28 21:59:00  7.589968 47.92188 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
888          1 2011-12-29 19:59:00  7.586910 47.93048 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
889          1 2011-12-30 17:59:00  7.596179 47.92308 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
890          1 2011-12-31 04:59:00  7.587268 47.91989 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
891          1 2012-01-01 02:59:00  7.586433 47.91984 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
892          1 2012-01-04 07:59:00  7.612507 47.95379 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
893          4 2010-05-01 02:59:00  7.620057 47.99007 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
894          4 2010-05-01 23:59:00  7.622088 47.98821 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
895          4 2010-05-02 20:59:00  7.623225 47.99002 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
896          4 2010-05-04 00:59:00  7.630547 47.97274 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
897          4 2010-05-04 21:59:00  7.623501 47.98742 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
898          4 2010-05-08 09:59:00  7.626074 47.98340 EPSG:4326-WGS48         gps
    study_area_id animals_age_class animals_sex
886            13                 a           f
887            13                 a           f
888            13                 a           f
889            13                 a           f
890            13                 a           f
891            13                 a           f
892            13                 a           f
893            13                 a           f
894            13                 a           f
895            13                 a           f
896            13                 a           f
897            13                 a           f
898            13                 a           f
```

The structure of the object I use to calculate the random points with, looks like this (object trk2):

```
# A tibble: 65 x 5
   id    data                    resample              hr        hr1         
   <chr> <list>                  <list>                <list>    <list>      
 1 M25   <track_xyt [867 x 7]>   <track_xyt [210 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 2 M23   <track_xyt [2,998 x 7]> <track_xyt [518 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 3 M24   <track_xyt [868 x 7]>   <track_xyt [236 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 4 M27   <track_xyt [466 x 7]>   <track_xyt [466 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 5 M28   <track_xyt [676 x 7]>   <track_xyt [676 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 6 M12   <track_xyt [346 x 7]>   <track_xyt [189 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 7 M14   <track_xyt [297 x 7]>   <track_xyt [131 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 8 M7    <track_xyt [645 x 7]>   <track_xyt [215 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
 9 M13   <track_xyt [395 x 7]>   <track_xyt [198 x 8]> <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
10 M41   <track_xyt [131 x 7]>   <track_xyt [64 x 8]>  <kde [7]> <sf [1 x 4]>
# ... with 55 more rows
```

The problem is, that I don't want 100 random points (n=100) for every individual but the amount of random points should be equal to the number of observations of the individuals. The observations are stored in the lists resample. I don't know how to change this piece of code to achieve this:

```
# calculate random points in individuals home range 
trk_id <- trk2 %>% mutate(random_used = map(hr1, function(z) {
                  z %>% random_points(n=100)
  }))
```

I appreciate every tip.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case, considering that 25 individuals are not that much, would be to subsect by id first. And apply the random points independently to each id (adjusting the number in the random_points parameter).
After this, I would group the individuals in a single dataframe/tibble again.

Best,
Alan

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see how you can make this a specific answer rather than general guidance

Comment: I agree with @camille. The OP provided a nice subset of the data.  You could use that to provide a specific demonstration of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but here is an example of a couple of ways to do this using the built-in amt_fisher dataset:

```
library(amt)
fisher = amt_fisher
fisher_trk = fisher %>% make_track(.x=x_, .y=y_, .t=t, id=id, crs=5070)
```

Method 1

```
fisher_hr = 
  fisher_trk %>%
  nest(data=-id) %>%
  mutate(hr = map(data, hr_mcp),
         rpts = map(hr, ~random_points(., n = nrow(.$data))))

# if you wanted to include the observations as well, change last line to:
rpts = map(hr, ~random_points(., n = nrow(.$data), presence=.$data)))
```

Method 2 - say you wanted a specific number of points per id, you can use purrr::map2

```
library(purrr)
pts.to.sample = data.frame(id=fisher_hr$id, n=c(10, 20, 30, 40)) 

fisher_hr = 
  fisher_trk %>%
  nest(data=-id) %>%
  mutate(hr = map(data, hr_mcp),
         rpts = map2(hr, pts.to.sample$n, function(x,y) random_points(x, n = y)))
```